# Select rows conditional on value of a column in specific order

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, for example like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(8, 2, 5, 1, 4), value=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

  ID value
1  8     a
2  2     b
3  5     c
4  1     d
5  4     e
```

I know how to select rows with a given value in the "ID" column. But how to get rows conditional on their "ID"-values in a specified order?

Example: How to extract "value" for rows with ID 4, 2 and 5 in the given order? The result I want to get is "e", "b", "c".

Using `%in%` gives me the results in wrong order:

```
df[df$ID %in% c(4, 2, 5), "value"]

[1] b c e
Levels: a b c d e
```

I found a workaround using rownames, but I feel like there must be a better solution to this.

```
# workaround
rownames(df) <- df$ID
df[as.character(c(4, 2, 5)), "value"]

[1] e b c
Levels: a b c d e
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` and `order` by a new introduced rank column   :

```
dat = merge(df,data.frame(ID=c(4,2,5),v=1:3))
dat[order(dat$v),"value"]
[1] e b c
```

Or one linear option:

```
with(merge(df,data.frame(ID=c(4,2,5),v=1:3)),value[order(v)])
```

Comment: I was thinking of using `merge`, too. Would it be faster than `sapply`?

Comment: I would say yes ( it uses basically `match` which is very fast), but you can benchmark and compare :)

Comment: I'll take your word for it now, and leave the benchmarking to OP.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was looking for an easier solution but apparently the sapply approach by @DavidePassaretti and agstudys solutions are as simple as possible. I prefer this answer as it is substantially faster than the sapply approach (benchmarking code at http://pastebin.com/iysD4FXz).

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(c(4,2,5), function(x) df[df$ID==x,"value"])
```

Comment: Thank you - I should have mentioned that I'm aware of iterative solutions but I wonder if there's some more direct approach.